# How to customize the react-apexcharts?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, charts, apexcharts

I'm using pie chart.
I want to customize the labels position of react-apexcharts.
In general, the labels are displayed on the right side of the pie-chart, but I want split them into 2 parts, half of them on the left side and another half of them on the right side.

Hide the labels first.
And then show made another area for labels but using this method I can't make the effect like default label which means that add bright on the chart when the mouse is over a label.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

first try checking the documentation to see if they have a prop that you can pass to get the job done if not then you can try going into your node_modules folder look for react-apexcharts.

You can edit it however you want once you are happy with it you can use

[Patch package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to create a patch so that everytime you run yarn or npm i ot doesn't get overwritten

hope this helps.